# Noise levels on high voltage power lines

Tags: noise, high-voltage, signal-processing, transmission-line

I'm doing Signal Processing on signals from high voltage transmission lines but I'm unsure of what noise levels I should be expecting and which types of noise occur in a power system (impulse, harmonic etc.)

The idea is to get signals from current and voltage transformers at substations to do fault detection and classification but the methods I employ are dependent on the noise I should be expecting.

I have seen various SNR values thrown around in different papers but I'm wondering whether anyone could point me to a good source on this topic or perhaps give a brief explanation.

Comment: What is the waveform of corona discharges during rainstorms? And how much energy per discharge?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few standards which seek to describe what electromagnetic immunity is necessary for equipment in power/substation environments.  I would recommend looking to **[IEC 61000-6-5](https://webstore.iec.ch/publication/23146)** for generic power station/substation EMC immunity requirements.  This will in turn point you to the appropriate levels in other IEC 61000-4-x standards.

IEC standards are copyrighted, so unfortunately I assume I cannot provide example values here.

Other standards describing immunity in substations for various specific circumstances:

- IEC 60870-2-1
- IEEE 1613 (which specifies many of the IEEE C37.90.x standards)
- IEC 60255-26